# Why adding to vector does not work while using iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, std

I have two code sample, which do exactly same thing. One is in C++03 and C++11.

**C++ 11**

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3};

    int count = 0;

    for each (auto it in v)
    {
        cout << it<<endl;

        if (count == 0)
        {
            count++;
            v.push_back(4);//adding value to vector
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**C++ 03**

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3};

    int count = 0;

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {

        cout << *it<<endl;

        if (count == 0)
        {
            count++;
            v.push_back(4);//adding value to vector
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Both the codes are giving following exception.

[image]

Now when I see vector::end() implementation,

```
iterator end() _NOEXCEPT
{   
// return iterator for end of mutable sequence
return (iterator(this->_Mylast, this));
}
```

Here, inline function clearly takes `_Mylast` to calculate end. So, when I add, it pointer will be incremented to next location, like `_Mylast++`. Why I am getting this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: "for each, in" isn't standard by the way. The c++11 ranged for is for( Type name : collection ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A vector stores its elements in contiguous memory. If that memory block needs to be reallocated, iterators become invalid.

If you need to modify the vector's size while iterating, iterate by index instead of `iterator`.

Another option is to use a different container with a different iterator behavior, for example a `list` will allow you to continue iterating as you insert items.

And finally, (dare I suggest this?) if you know the maximum size your vector will grow to, `.reserve()` it before iterating over it. This will ensure it doesn't get reallocated during your loop. I am not sure if this behavior is guaranteed by the standard though (maybe someone can chime in); I would definitely not do it, considering iterating by index is perfectly safe.

Comment: `resize` doesn't help much if followed by `push_back` - `at` or `operator[]` should be used in that case. `reserve` works with `push_back` as it doesn't change the size, only the capacity. Personally, I stick with the "don't modify what you're iterating over" principle.

Comment: `std::deque` is a good alternative to `std::vector` if you want to keep iterators valid.

Answer (score 4):

Your `push_back` is invalidating the iterator you're using in the `for` loop, because the vector is reallocating its memory, which invalidates all iterators to elements of the vector.

The idiomatic solution for this is to use an `insert_iterator`, like the one you get from calling `std::back_insterter` on the vector. Then you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  auto inserter = std::back_inserter(v);
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    inserter = i;

  for(const auto item : v)
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}
```

And it will ensure its own validity even through reallocation calls of the underlying container.

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd13fb55bf3caf6).